# Practice of my meditation

Tags: vipassana, mindfulness

When Itry to reach to the toothbrush in the morning I saw my mind intention to take  it and the hand movement is felt like as I was in a magnetic  field. What is it ?

Answer (score 2):

> When Itry to reach to the toothbrush in the morning I saw my mind intention to take it and the hand movement is felt like as I was in a magnetic field. What is it ?

All actions are preceeded by the mind. An intention (Cetana in Pali), which is a mental formation, is the initiator behind the subsequent action done by the body - in this case the bodily action of reaching out for the toothbrush.

In reality that movement can be broken up into many smaller steps suchs extending the arm, flexing the wrist, flexing the fingers etc. There's also the feeling of touch sensation when holding the toothbrush and the awareness/consciousness of all the movements.

Beginning to see intentions is an important, vital step in understanding how the mind/body complex works. It's a sign that introspection is beginning to happen.

My advice would be to find a good teacher or undertake a meditation course to develop your practice further.

Comment: interesting point; how about 'actions' which are done reactively cf through specific reasoning, eg maintaining balance when moving/ walking over uneven terrain, maybe maintaining balance is somewhat considered overall, yet specific adjustments are simply done while moving & without specific pondering (for a somewhat practiced walker)

Answer (score 0):

Intention = intention

Mind = mind

Magnetic field = magnetic field

Vipassana = clearly seeing of not-self (anatta); of elements (dhatu).

"I", "my", "I" = wrong view = source of suffering

Comment: Is it mindfulness?

Answer (score 0):

You were ´seeing’ reality as it truly ‘operates’:

Intention = desire = condition

(Body with arm, toothbrush at hand, etc., all conditions)

Mind = responsive naturing of reality (clarity, light, responsiveness)

Arm moving toward toothbrush = response

(Dropping toothbrush in sink = evidence that attention was distracted ☺️)